# Enviar texto desde un Java Class a un JTextField de un JFrameForm

Tags: java

En mi java class

```
 public void mensaje() {
    interfaz i = new interfaz();

    String msj = "Hola";
    i.txt_km.setText(msj);

}
```

En mi Jframe

```
private void btn_mostrarMsjMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        pila pila = new pila();
        pila.mensaje();
       
}
```

Lo que quiero es que desde mi javaclass mandar un texto a mi jtextfield que esta en mi jframe al hacer click en jbutton
Al momento de presionar el botón no sucede nada

Agradecería mucho su ayuda soy un total novato, trate de simplificar mi duda lo máximo posible para darme a entender, agradecería una explicación para un novato.

Comment: Depura el flujo del código. Puedes ir poniendo `System.println` para verificar que el código entra en cada parte. Luego, podrás pasar a ver si el elemento `i` se crea realmente. Luego, tendrás que mostrarlo.

Comment: Aprecio su respuesta y si con un System.println se muestra, pero al quererlo mostrar en el Jtextfield no muestra nada

Comment: Pero no se ve el contexto. ¿Dónde está el contenedor del `JTextField`, de qué modo lo agregas a ese contenedor? ¿De qué modo muestras el contenedor? No veo nada de ese en tu código.

Comment: Tu código no compila, te recomiendo poner un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo crea un nuevo jFrame cada que ejecutas el método "mensaje()", lo que tienes que hacer es sacar el valor del String "msj" desde el jFrame.

Primero que nada debes declarar la variable msj como pública, o en su defecto, crear un método get.

```
public String msj = "Hola";
```

Nota, esta variable msj tiene que estar declarada fuera del método "mensaje()", tu clase posee un nombre, en la parte arriba podrás ver el paquete y debajo el nombre de tu clase de la siguiente manera:

```
package paquete;

public class TuClase{

//Aquí deberás declarar tu variable msj
public String msj = "Hola";

}
```

Posteriormente, después de haber declarado correctamente la variable, en tu jFrame deberás colocar lo siguiente:

```
private void btn_mostrarMsjMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        pila pila = new pila();
        pila.mensaje();

//Este será el comando que te permita sacar el valor de tu variable en la clase pila
txt_km.setText( pila.msj );
       
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias ehh, como un error tan pequeño me detuvo mucho tiempo, un abrazo hermano y muchisimas gracias, exitos!!